# How to use a custom SVM kernel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, gaussian

I'd like to implement my own Gaussian kernel in Python, just for exercise. I'm using:
`sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)` but I really don't understand what is going on.

I expect the function my_kernel to be called with the columns of the `X` matrix as parameters, instead I got it called with `X`, `X` as arguments. Looking at the examples things are not clearer.

What am I missing?

This is my code:

```
'''
Created on 15 Nov 2014

@author: Luigi
'''
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def svm_class(fileName):

    data = scipy.io.loadmat(fileName)
    X = data['X']
    y = data['y']

    f = svm.SVC(kernel = 'rbf', gamma=50, C=1.0)
    f.fit(X,y.flatten())
    plotData(np.hstack((X,y)), X, f)

    return

def plotData(arr, X, f):

    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    ax.scatter(arr[arr[:,2]==0][:,0], arr[arr[:,2]==0][:,1], c='r', marker='o', label='Zero')
    ax.scatter(arr[arr[:,2]==1][:,0], arr[arr[:,2]==1][:,1], c='g', marker='+', label='One')

    h = .02  # step size in the mesh
    # create a mesh to plot in
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))


    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    Z = f.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.contour(xx, yy, Z)



    plt.xlim(np.min(arr[:,0]), np.max(arr[:,0]))
    plt.ylim(np.min(arr[:,1]), np.max(arr[:,1]))
    plt.show()
    return


def gaussian_kernel(x1,x2):
    sigma = 0.5
    return np.exp(-np.sum((x1-x2)**2)/(2*sigma**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fileName = 'ex6data2.mat'
    svm_class(fileName)
```

Answer (score 24):

After reading the answer above, and some other questions and sites ([1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels), [2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html#example-svm-plot-custom-kernel-py,), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025334/predicting-with-chi-squared-kernel-for-multilabel-using-sklearn,), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92101/prediction-with-scikit-and-an-precomputed-kernel-svm,), [5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115439/how-to-apply-a-gaussian-radial-basis-function-kernel-pca-to-nonlinear-data))), I put this together for a gaussian kernel in [`svm.SVC()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

Call `svm.SVC()` with `kernel=precomputed`.

Then compute a [Gram Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) a.k.a. Kernel Matrix (often abbreviated as K).

Then use this Gram Matrix as the first argument (*i.e.* X) to [`svm.SVC().fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit):

I start with the [following code](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/dataset3Params.py):

```
C=0.1
model = svmTrain(X, y, C, "gaussian")
```

that calls `sklearn.svm.SVC()` in [`svmTrain()`](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/svmTrain.py), and then `sklearn.svm.SVC().fit()`:

```
from sklearn import svm

if kernelFunction == "gaussian":
    clf = svm.SVC(C = C, kernel="precomputed")
    return clf.fit(gaussianKernelGramMatrix(X,X), y)
```

the Gram Matrix computation - used as a parameter to `sklearn.svm.SVC().fit()` - is done in [`gaussianKernelGramMatrix()`](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/gaussianKernelGramMatrix.py):

```
import numpy as np

def gaussianKernelGramMatrix(X1, X2, K_function=gaussianKernel):
    """(Pre)calculates Gram Matrix K"""

    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X1.shape[0], X2.shape[0]))
    for i, x1 in enumerate(X1):
        for j, x2 in enumerate(X2):
            gram_matrix[i, j] = K_function(x1, x2)
    return gram_matrix
```

which uses [`gaussianKernel()`](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/gaussianKernel.py) to get a radial basis function kernel between x1 and x2 ([a measure of similarity based on a gaussian distribution centered on x1 with sigma=0.1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110316/19809)):

```
def gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma=0.1):

    # Ensure that x1 and x2 are column vectors
    x1 = x1.flatten()
    x2 = x2.flatten()

    sim = np.exp(- np.sum( np.power((x1 - x2),2) ) / float( 2*(sigma**2) ) )

    return sim
```

Then, once the model is trained with this custom kernel, we predict with ["the [custom] kernel between the test data and the training data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025334/predicting-with-chi-squared-kernel-for-multilabel-using-sklearn):

```
predictions = model.predict( gaussianKernelGramMatrix(Xval, X) )
```

In short, to use a custom SVM gaussian kernel, you can use this snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

def gaussianKernelGramMatrixFull(X1, X2, sigma=0.1):
    """(Pre)calculates Gram Matrix K"""

    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X1.shape[0], X2.shape[0]))
    for i, x1 in enumerate(X1):
        for j, x2 in enumerate(X2):
            x1 = x1.flatten()
            x2 = x2.flatten()
            gram_matrix[i, j] = np.exp(- np.sum( np.power((x1 - x2),2) ) / float( 2*(sigma**2) ) )
    return gram_matrix

X=...
y=...
Xval=...

C=0.1
clf = svm.SVC(C = C, kernel="precomputed")
model = clf.fit( gaussianKernelGramMatrixFull(X,X), y )

p = model.predict( gaussianKernelGramMatrixFull(Xval, X) )
```

Comment: What is your "Xval" in this case? Is that the training set to run predictions on?
Also, since the inputs to "gaussianKernelGramMatrixFull" have to be the same dimensions, do you manually have to resize X to generate the Gram correctly?

Comment: @VinitNayak not quite - `Xval`s are values whose predictions we want to get. We trained on the training set `x` with the known labels `y`, but we don't know what the labels for `Xval` are, so we predict them.

Comment: @VinitNayak `X` and `Xval` don't need to be the same size. they just have to have the same number of columns (the `n` in an `m` by `n` matrix), as you would expect your training data and your data-to-predict to have (i.e. they shouldn't have the same number of samples but they should have the same number of features)

Comment: My `X` is a 622x9 matrix, `y` is 622x1 matrix, `Xval` (which is my cross validation set) is 266x9. When I run the above, I get the following error when predicting:

`svm/base.py", line 455, in _validate_for_predict
    (X.shape[1], self.shape_fit_[0]))

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 9 should be equal to 622, the number of samples at training time`

Comment: you have 622 samples w 9 features in your X? in that case, you have 266 test data points also with 9 features. you probably just need to transpose the array. You can do this in numpy as `my_array.T`

Answer (score 10):

For efficiency reasons, SVC assumes that your kernel is a function accepting [**two matrices of samples**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels), `X` and `Y` (it will use two identical ones only during training) and you should return **a matrix** `G` where:

```
G_ij = K(X_i, Y_j)
```

and `K` is your "point-level" kernel function.

So either implement a gaussian kernel that works in such a generic way, or add a "proxy" function like:

```
def proxy_kernel(X,Y,K):
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        for j, y in enumerate(Y):
            gram_matrix[i, j] = K(x, y)
    return gram_matrix
```

and use it like:

```
from functools import partial
correct_gaussian_kernel = partial(proxy_kernel, K=gaussian_kernel)
```

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand, probably because I am a very beginner in ML. Shouldn't be enough returning a square matrix with n=n_rows(X), the elements being all the combinations between X[:,0] and X[:,1]?

Comment: As I said, it won't be always called with two X's as arguments, so no. Furthermore your data is multidimensional, so X[:,0] is just first dimension of each vector which has nothing to do here.

Comment: And what should I return?

Comment: A Gram matrix, exactly as it is written in the answer. matrix where i'th row and j'th column consists kernel value between i'th vector from first array and j'th from the second one, so

kernel(X,Y)_{ij} = K(X_i, Y_j)

Comment: @lejlot my question might be directly related because I am using self-computed kernel. Can you please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564504/in-self-compute-kernelx-raise-valueerrorx-shape0-should-be-equal-to-x-sha