# I am trying to implement SVM in scikit-learn with custom RBF kernel ,But it is showing an error ,what to do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import math
import numpy.linalg as la

df = pd.read_csv("DataWithoutHeader162.csv")
df.columns = ['Temperature','Humidity','Windspeed','Traffic','PM 2.5']
#print(df.head())

forecast_col = 'PM 2.5'
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(1)
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label','PM 2.5'] , 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
df.dropna(inplace = True)

y = np.array(df['label'])
df.dropna(inplace = True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05) 


#kernel definition
def radial_basis(gamma=10):
    return lambda x, y: np.exp(-gamma*la.norm(np.subtract(x, y)))

#SupportVectorMachine with radial_basis Kernel
clf_SVM_radial_basis = SVC(kernel = radial_basis())
clf_SVM_radial_basis.fit(X_train,y_train)
confidence3 = clf_SVM_radial_basis.score(X_test,y_test)
print("Confidence of SVM with radial_basis Kernel = ",(confidence3*100),"%")
```

This code shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "F:\MachineLearningPyCodes\SvmOnDelhiAqiDataPrbf.py", line 68, in  
module  
clf_SVM_radial_basis.fit(X_train,y_train)  
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 189, in fit  
fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)  
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 230, in   
_dense_fit  
if X.shape[0] != X.shape[1]:  
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I tried different methods but I am not able to format my dataset as per required I guess, please tell me a method to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also confused by how `SVC`'s `kernel` argument worked. It's not just the kernel function `radial_basis` as you have it; it actually has to return the **Gram matrix**. You can see this in the sklearn documentation:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels

To summarize that section: you have two choices.

(1) either plug the Gram matrix directly into the `fit()` method (not just plain `X_train`), and use `kernel='precomputed'`; or

(2) write a function that returns the Gram matrix, and then you can pass that new function instead to `kernel`.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962159/how-to-use-a-custom-svm-kernel) has good examples. Adapting what they wrote, you could do it this way. I'll use the second method, and I'll keep your original `radial_basis` for illustration.

```
def radial_basis(x, y, gamma=10):
    return np.exp(-gamma * la.norm(np.subtract(x, y)))

def proxy_kernel(X, Y, K=radial_basis):
    """Another function to return the gram_matrix,
    which is needed in SVC's kernel or fit
    """
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        for j, y in enumerate(Y):
            gram_matrix[i, j] = K(x, y)
    return gram_matrix

clf_SVM_radial_basis = SVC(kernel=proxy_kernel) # Note that it's proxy_kernel here now
clf_SVM_radial_basis.fit(X_train, y_train)
```